# Get content-type of images in HTML file with Curl get_info

Tags: php, curl, echo, content-type, simple-html-dom

I'm using Curl with Simple HTML DOM like this:

```
$url = $_GET['url'];
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
...
...
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load($curl_scraped_page, true, false);

foreach($html->find('img') as $a) {
    echo $a;
}
```

This will echo the images. So now I'm trying to get the content type which is `image/jpeg` so I tried:

```
$type = (curl_getinfo($a, content_type));
echo $type;
```

And:

```
  echo curl_getinfo($a, content_type);
```

I'm not getting anything (blank screen). How do I use `get_info` on every single element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of, to get to content type from the fetch document use the constant `CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE`.

```
$type = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);
echo $type;
```

Second, you only fetched the HTML not the images. Saying that $a outputs the images is *wrong*. You output HTML `<img src="">`. If you do that in the browser you see the images, but that's just because the browser fetches those images at client side.

The easiest way to get the the content type, would be to use check the file extension.

```
$ext = pathinfo($a['src'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

If you really need to use the file extension, you have to do additional curl calls. Best to use curl_multi to do these in parallel.

```
$mh = curl_multi_init();

foreach($html->find('img') as $a) {
    $src = $a['src']; // You probably need to rewrite relative URL to absolute URLs
    $ch = curl_init($src);
    $ch = curl_set_opt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "HEAD");
    curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $ch);
    $handles[] = $ch;
}

$running = null;
do {
    curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
} while ($running);

foreach ($handles as $ch) {
    $src = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
    $type = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);
    $image_types[$src] = $type;
}
```

*Code is untested*

Note that the received content-type can never be fully trusted and should never be used for security measures. If you want to be sure, download all the images (GET request instead of HEAD request) and use the [fileinfo extension](http://php.net/fileinfo).

Comment: I can't get it to work, but I will accept as answer if nothing else comes along because it does make sense to me, I must be doing something wrong...Thank you very much

Comment: Sorry, I said `$a`, but you need to use the curl handler `$ch`.

Comment: Okay, now I see that I really misread your question. Sorry and hold on.